# Body click, close menu if open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('#menuToggle, .menu-close').on('click', function(){
    $('#menuToggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('body').toggleClass('body-push-toleft');
    $('#theMenu').toggleClass('menu-open');
    $('#menuToggle').find($(".fa")).toggleClass('fa-rotate-180');
    $("body").toggleClass("active");
});
```

this is my javascript  code for navigation menu slide form right side.It is working properly but i want to close this menu when once it is open on click or close menu click anywhere on body and toggle button?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take some time on reading the FAQ, especially regarding how to ask good questions here. A nice way is, to sum up your question in the headline. Please also be aware, that most users like to see what you have tried to far. So its best to include that.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples on w3schools, you can use any of them. But what I personally liked was this:

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that its same as i'm see on the W3 school .
Again Thanks

Comment: Welcome buddy :-)